# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges called every 47 sec while application in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

`startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is added for background and delegate "`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`"  is called in every `47 sec` while application in background.
If application is on same place i don't want to hit the server api to submit the location, if location has changed then I want to submit the lat& long to server.

It's drain the iphone battery. I want to save battery drain which occured by our application.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please show some code?

Comment: You may compare previous and latest coordinate and put some condition that difference > Some value then Call your webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the desiredAccuracy, distanceFilter, headingFilter(if you need it) properly, where you have initialised locationmanager.

```
/* Pinpoint our location with the following accuracy:
 *
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation  highest + sensor data
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyBest               highest     
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters   10 meters   
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters      100 meters
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer          1000 meters 
 *     kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers    3000 meters
 */
self.your_locationManager_object.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

/* Notify changes when device has moved x meters.
 * Default value is kCLDistanceFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;

/* Notify heading changes when heading is > 5.
 * Default value is kCLHeadingFilterNone: all movements are reported.
 */
self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;

// update location
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```